Trying to install blpapi. Cannot find blpapi_element.h
I am trying to install blpapi on Windows 11 in a vm in a Mac.
I installed Visual Studio 2022 for the MSVC 14 dependency. I used this command to install blpapi:  pip install --index- url=https://blpapi.bloomberg.com/repository/releases/python/simple/ blpapi
I am using python version 3.12.
I am getting this error:
Looking in indexes: https://blpapi.bloomberg.com/repository/releases/python/simple/
Collecting blpapi
Using cached https://blpapi.bloomberg.com/repository/releases/python/blpapi-3.24.10.tar.gz (233 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: blpapi
Building wheel for blpapi (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Building wheel for blpapi (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [73 lines of output]
BLPAPI_DEPENDENCY environment variable isn't defined
C:\Users\neela\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-arm64\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py:251: _IncompatibleBdistWheel: wheel.bdist_wheel is deprecated, please import it from setuptools
!!
          ********************************************************************************
          Ensure that any custom bdist_wheel implementation is a subclass of
          setuptools.command.bdist_wheel.bdist_wheel.

          By 2025-Oct-15, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
          or your builds will no longer be supported.

          See https://github.com/pypa/wheel/pull/631 for details.
          ********************************************************************************

  !!
    return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
  BLPAPI_DEPENDENCY environment variable isn't defined
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\abstractsession.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\auth.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\chandle.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\constant.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\correlationid.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\ctypesutils.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\datatype.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\datetime.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\debug.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\debug_environment.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\diagnosticsutil.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\element.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\event.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\eventdispatcher.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\eventformatter.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\exception.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\highresclock.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\identity.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\internals.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\logging.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\message.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\name.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\names.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\providersession.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\pycbhelpers.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\request.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\requesttemplate.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\resolutionlist.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\schema.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\service.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\session.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\sessionoptions.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\subscriptionlist.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\topic.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\topiclist.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\typehints.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\utils.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\version.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\zfputil.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  copying src\blpapi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi
  creating build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi\test
  copying src\blpapi\test\messageformatter.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi\test
  copying src\blpapi\test\messageproperties.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi\test
  copying src\blpapi\test\testutil.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi\test
  copying src\blpapi\test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-arm64-cpython-312\blpapi\test
  running build_ext
  building 'blpapi.ffiutils' extension
  creating build\temp.win-arm64-cpython-312\Release\src\blpapi
  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\bin\HostARM64\ARM64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I.\include -IC:\Users\neela\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-arm64\include -IC:\Users\neela\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-arm64\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/blpapi/ffi_utils.c /Fobuild\temp.win-arm64-cpython-312\Release\src/blpapi/ffi_utils.obj
  ffi_utils.c
  src/blpapi/ffi_utils.c(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'blpapi_element.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\bin\\HostARM64\\ARM64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for blpapi
Failed to build blpapi
[notice] A new release of pip is available: 24.2 -> 24.3.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (blpapi)
Can someone help me please?
Thanks.
